# Traversing a circular arc without computing the center point

Tags: geometry, limits, circles

Consider the following diagram.  I am given the values of $h$, $a$, and $\theta$, along with the positions at both endpoints of chord $a$.  Using these values, I would like to consider a traversal from one endpoint to the other at a constant rate along arc $s$, and be able to calculate the current position at any given time.

[image]

The trick is that with $a$ being held constant, $h$ and $\theta$ can go to zero while the center of the circle heads off to infinity.  As a result, if my method of computing the point on the arc depends on computing the center point of the circle or its radius then it will break down as $h$ approaches zero.  This, despite the fact that the arc segment to be traversed is still nice and finite.

I would like to avoid introducing a special case for small values of $h$ and instead find a way of expressing the point purely as a function of $\theta$ and a linear combination of $h$ and $a$, all of which are consistently defined even if they happen to go to zero.  Is such a parameterization possible?

Comment: Can you evaluate $$\frac{a}{2}\cot\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$ for all interesting $a$ and $\theta$?

Comment: One way, you see, is $$\begin{cases}x(t) = \frac{a}{2}\left( \cot\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\sin(t \theta) - \cos(t \theta) + 1 \right) \\ y(t) = \frac{a}{2}\left( \cot\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\left(1 - \cos(t \theta)\right) - \sin(t \theta) \right) \end{cases}$$with $0 \le t \le 1$.

Comment: Unfortunately, $cot (\theta / 2)$ becomes undefined as $\theta$ approaches zero.

Comment: True; you only mentioned *small* values, so I wasn't sure if you needed an expression that can handle $\theta = 0$. Of course, both $\cot\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\sin(t\theta)$ and $\cot\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\left(1-\cos(t\theta)\right)$ can be expanded as series in $\theta$ without such issues.